# Calculating a building's shade with building height

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, physics, python

I work in GIS and to create a shade layer of a building, I need to "translate" the geometry/building or permanenently move it.

But I just need some help with my formula based on this [video](https://youtu.be/KqpTDK3s70I).

A = tangent of the sunlight's angle

B = Building height

C = Shadow length

So, to know how much the geometry/building will translate/move from its original X and Y coordinates

$$
A = \frac BC
$$
$$
C = \frac BA
$$

Is this correct? This [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/324175/146811) from GIS SE says it's cos(sunlight angle) * building height.

For now, I used `round((height/math.tan(45)),3)` to translate/move the geometry. This is the result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming that "sunlight's angle" means $\alpha$, the sun's angle of elevation (the angle between a shaft of sunlight and the horizontal ground ray beneath it), then yes, $\tan \alpha = B/C$.  This is the "slope" equals "rise" over "run" relationship.  Drawing yourself a picture will probably help you realize whether that is all you want out of this.

Comment: What seems to be the issue is whether $C$ represents the "length of shadow" along the ground (from building foot to tip of shadow) or the distance diagonally from building top to tip of shadow).  Your words make me think you want $C$ to be the former (horizontal) distance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I believe what I need is the latter as the building + shade are both considered "obstruction" in my use case. I added the screenshots. @hardmath

Comment: Now it looks like buildings have only tops with no walls. Cosine is obviously incorrect, because it does not describes situation when shadow is longer than building height.